# Fibers of flat morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a surjective flat projective morphism between Noetherian schemes. Assume that $Y$ is non-reduced. Denote by $g:X \times_Y Y_{red} \to Y_{red}$ the pull-back of $f$ by the natural morphism, $\rho:Y_{red} \to Y$. 
Consider a point $y \in Y$ meaning $y$ is a zero dimensional scheme such that there exists a closed immersion of $y$ into $Y$. Denote by $y_{red}:=\rho^{-1}(y)$. We already know that if $y$ is a reduced point, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is isomorphic to $g^{-1}(y_{red}) \times y$. If $y$ is not reduced, under what conditions is it possible that $f^{-1}(y)$ isomorphic to $g^{-1}(y_{red}) \times y$? Any ideas or references in this direction will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at an example. This is not a research level question.

Comment: @anon: I would be very grateful if you could suggest an example